# gcloud authentication error while transferring these files.. Your "OAuth 2.0 Service Account" credentials are invalid

Tags: oauth-2.0, gcloud, gsutil

We have a gsutil service that uploads files to google cloud bucket. There are many files in the source folder that are getting successfully uploaded to bucket except one. Below is the error logged while transferring this particular file.

**gcloud authentication error while transferring these files..
Your "OAuth 2.0 Service Account" credentials are invalid. Please run
 $ gcloud auth login**

Please note there are many files that are transferred before and after this file and none of them have had any issues.Also , there are no changes done to Service account details.Kindly note when this file was again attempted to be uploaded , it got uploaded successfully. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: What version of gcloud you are using? Is there anything special about this file, is it very large? How long does it take to transfer all files?

Comment: Yes the file size is relatively large .. around 390MB... Apart from the file size there is nothing else specific to this file.

Gcloud version details:
Google Cloud SDK 130.0.0
bundled-python 2.7.10
gcloud
gsutil 4.21

Please note , this same file has got uploaded successfully in less than 2 mins when tried again.
When the upload failed for this file, there were about 20 files that were sequentially uploaded to cloud in less than 2 mins just before this file which was last in order.Just thought this information may be of use.None of these other 20 files had volume more than 100MB.

Comment: Service account is used to generate access tokens which have expiration. Usually they are valid for about one hour, perhaps it expires in the middle and fails to refresh.  Not sure... I would suggest to file a bug here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues, gsutil team is generally prompt to respond.

Comment: Thank you .. I have logged the issue on the github community ... will share their response ..